# White bar at top of html page Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

A white bar appears at the top of the page for a section that is meant to contain an image. By removing different parts of the webpage I found out deleting the opening and closing labels fixes it but I still need to include them. Also, removing bootstrap also fixes the problem but again, I'll need bootstrap later. I really don't know what's causing the issue.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: -250px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(4, 11, 20);
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.sidebar header {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: rgb(4, 11, 20);
  user-select: none;
}

.sidebar ul a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 65px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 40px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

ul li:hover a {
  padding-left: 45px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar ul a i {
  margin-right: 8px;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

label #menu-open,
label #menu-close {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label #menu-open {
  left: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  transition: all .5s;
}

label #menu-close {
  z-index: 1111;
  left: 195px;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 9px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
  transition-delay: .5s;
}

#check:checked~.sidebar {
  left: 0;
}

#check:checked~label #menu-open {
  left: 250px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#check:checked~label #menu-close {
  opacity: 1;
}

section {
  background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1779487/pexels-photo-1779487.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-designecologist-1779487.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Tyler Wong Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label for="check">
          <i class="bi bi-list" id="menu-open"></i>
          <i class="bi bi-x" id="menu-close"></i>
        </label>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <header>Tyler Wong</header>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-house-door"></i> Home </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-person"></i> About </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-code-square"></i> Projects </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-mailbox"></i> Contact </a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <section></section>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: Picture of the webpage currently.]

Comment: You're missing a "<" in the beginning. Also did you inspect the code for the white bar in the browser developer mode?

Comment: Flow of html. If you put `<section>` at the top of html body does it fix it?

Comment: Putting <section> at the top fixes it as well as the solution I marked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `<label for="check">` you are putting this element in top as `inline-block`, a simple solution is change it to

`<label for="check" style="display: inline;">`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
.sidebar{
  top:0;
  position: fixed;
  left: -250px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(4,11,20);
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.sidebar header{
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: rgb(4,11,20);
  user-select: none;
}
.sidebar ul a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 65px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 40px;
  transition:0.3s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
ul li:hover a{
  padding-left: 45px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar ul a i{
  margin-right: 8px;
}
#check{
  display: none;
}
label #menu-open,label #menu-close{
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label #menu-open{
  left: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  transition: all .5s;
}

label #menu-close{
  z-index: 1111;
  left: 195px;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 9px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
  transition-delay: .5s;
}
#check:checked ~ .sidebar{
  left:0;
}
#check:checked ~ label #menu-open{
  left: 250px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#check:checked ~ label #menu-close{
  opacity:1;
}

section {
  background: red no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <!-- Ignore for Code Snippet -->
    <!-- <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <title>Tyler Wong Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check" style="display: inline;">
      <i class="bi bi-list" id="menu-open"></i>
      <i class="bi bi-x" id="menu-close"></i>
    </label>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <header>Tyler Wong</header>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-house-door"></i> Home </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-person"></i> About </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-code-square"></i> Projects </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> <i class="bi bi-mailbox"></i> Contact </a> </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <section></section>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had runned same code on my local the issue seems to be here

```
label {
     display: inline-block;
 }
```

It fixed the error comment this display property and see it will reflect

Answer (score 1):

If you move `<section>` to the top of the html it should go away do to the flow of html. Your other option is to give it a negative position

```
background: {
  position: relative;
  top:-25px;
}
```